# Android's WorkManager's Simultaneous Job Count/Max

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Does WorkManager have a cap to the number of jobs that run at the same time?

Very simple example:

- Click button, creating 10 one-time jobs
- Enqueue them all
- 3 jobs run at a time, instead of all 10 as expected

---

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        queue.setOnClickListener {
            val jobs = mutableListOf<OneTimeWorkRequest>()

            for( i in 1..10 ) {
                jobs += OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>()
                    .setInputData(workDataOf("key" to i))
                    .build()
            }

            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(jobs)
        }
    }
}

class MyWorker: Worker() {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val jobId = inputData.getInt("key", -1)

        Log.d("worker", "starting job: $jobId")

        Completable.timer(10, SECONDS).blockingGet()

        Log.d("worker", "job finished: $jobId")

        return SUCCESS
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
08-30 14:03:10.392  9825  9855 D worker  : starting job: 2
08-30 14:03:10.396  9825  9856 D worker  : starting job: 3
08-30 14:03:10.400  9825  9854 D worker  : starting job: 1
08-30 14:03:20.421  9825  9855 D worker  : job finished: 2
08-30 14:03:20.421  9825  9856 D worker  : job finished: 3
08-30 14:03:20.421  9825  9854 D worker  : job finished: 1
08-30 14:03:20.442  9825  9856 D worker  : starting job: 4
08-30 14:03:20.448  9825  9854 D worker  : starting job: 5
08-30 14:03:20.450  9825  9855 D worker  : starting job: 6
08-30 14:03:30.444  9825  9856 D worker  : job finished: 4
08-30 14:03:30.449  9825  9854 D worker  : job finished: 5
08-30 14:03:30.451  9825  9855 D worker  : job finished: 6
08-30 14:03:30.474  9825  9856 D worker  : starting job: 7
08-30 14:03:30.477  9825  9855 D worker  : starting job: 8
08-30 14:03:30.480  9825  9854 D worker  : starting job: 9
08-30 14:03:40.476  9825  9856 D worker  : job finished: 7
08-30 14:03:40.478  9825  9855 D worker  : job finished: 8
08-30 14:03:40.481  9825  9854 D worker  : job finished: 9
08-30 14:03:40.497  9825  9856 D worker  : starting job: 10
08-30 14:03:50.500  9825  9856 D worker  : job finished: 10
```

Comment: did you got any updates on this?

Comment: No, I have not received any updates on this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of jobs that can run at the same time are actually determined by a thread pool that you configure. The default `Executor` is defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-1.0-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/Configuration.java#118).

Typically when you are using the `Worker` base class, you are associating an instance of the `Worker` to a thread on this `Executor`. If you want greater control on which thread your `Worker` is associated with, you might want to take a look at `CoroutineWorker` or `ListenableWorker`.

The number of threads in the default `Executor` are determined by the number  of cores on the device. If you want all 10 jobs to run at the same time you have to do the following:

- Disable the default `WorkManager` initializer (by disabling manifest merging for the content provider).
- Initialize `WorkManager` on `Application.onCreate()` or your own `ContentProvider`. You need to do this here because the OS can ask previously scheduled `Worker`s to run. For more information look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#initialize(android.content.Context,%20androidx.work.Configuration)).

```
val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
    // Defines a thread pool with 10 threads. 
    // Ideally you would choose a number that is dynamic based on the number 
    // of cores on the device.
    .setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
    .build()

WorkManager.initialize(context, configuration)
```

In the above example I am creating a fixed size thread pool with 10 threads (which in turn can handle 10 `Workers`). Now when you enqueue your `Worker`s you will see all of them execute at the same time.

Comment: A limiting factor to consider for the number of workers is if you have dependencies between workers. You will get an IllegalStateException "Data cannot occupy more than 10240 bytes when serialized" if you have a WorkerB that depends on 1000 WorkerA's that pass some minimal amount of data.

Comment: While this sounds logical, in my case I set this to a single-threaded executor. But it still starts `doWork` of multiple workers simultaneously. The configuration is correct, I made sure it gets called. Just super confused right now...